# How to access a dialog from a view?

Tags: android, dialog

This question is about the concept of what I am attempting to code.

I Have an Activity 
"public class Board extends Activity {" 
which has "setContentView(myBoard)" where myBoard is an instance of 
"class NewBoard extends View implements OnTouchListener{"
NewBoard draws graphics with onDraw and also draws graphical buttons. 
A click on a button called "Solve" makes a call to another class
"public class SKO {" which has no visual componants and does a calcuation, the results of which are redrawn by the graphic view.

This all works well.

I now want to call a Dialog from more graphically drawn buttons on the NewBoard View.

In the "top" class - Board, I have suitable code in
"protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {"
I know this code is good because if I add a showDialog(int),(an Alertdialog with a cancel button) to the onCreate of Board,then on running the class Board, the dialog comes up, and when cancelled, my graphics are working underneath.

My problem is ************

that I can't find a way to call the showDialog(int) within Board from my graphics View (NewBoard).

I have tried adding the "protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {" to my graphics View (NewBoard) but I believe it can only be added to an activity.
I would very much appreciate some advice.

Comment: I have hard time understanding your question but why not Storing a reference to your dialog once it gets created from the Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you define a Listener interface like NewBoardListener (not a great name, but good enough for an example). Your Board class can register with your NewBoard view as a NewBoardListener. Let's assume the button event in your NewBoard view has something to do with "View Status" then your NewBoardListener interface can define a method called something like onViewStatus(). When the user taps the button on the NewBoard view, you make a callback to your newBoardListener.onViewStatus(). Then in your Board class which implements the NewBoardListener interface, in your onViewStatus method, you call showDialog(int).